# Configuring domain name for Azure app where domain registrar does not provide CName or forwarding option (ccTLD domain)

Tags: azure, dns, cname, a-records

I registered a [ccTLD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain), and my domain registrar does not provide a CName, instead it lists nameservers solely. How do I configure domain forwarding for my web app which happens to be hosted on an Azure VM? The [documentation here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/) only deals with setting a CName or an A Record. Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a DNS hosting provider to host your nameserver. HE.Net is one of the many out there and you can register at dns.he.net. Taking them as the example, set ns1.he.net and ns2.he.net as NS records for your domain provider. Now at dns.he.net, set up the CNAME or A records for your machine.

Comment: Sounds pretty simple. Let me give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Hmm, seems changing nameservers takes up to many hours! Is that your experience too?

Comment: DNS entries are cached from a few hours to a day. You can wait for the new entries to propagate or try clearing your machine's DNS cache.